# Use ejs template name inside template itself

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, templates, ejs

I am using ejs templates to generate some contents inside different divs.

let's say it looks kind of like this:

```
<% include test1 %>

<% include test2 %>

<% include test3 %>
```

and in each of these templates, I would like to know what template I'm in automatically. for example, let's say I'm in "templatei.ejs" file (where i is the index of the ith template). now is there any way for me to know the template name inside it?

this is how each template file looks:

```
<div>
<h2>header info</h2>
<p>some text comes here</p>
<a href="/<% this.fileName() %>">now I want this url to be a link to a seperate page that only loads one template<a>
</div>
```

this.fileName() will not work it was just to express what I mean.
I actually want to add a link to a separate page for each of my divs.

> the reason I don't use javascript to generate urls is that I want
>   crawlers to find it and I dont think a crawler would scrape the page
>   after js changes.

Comment: Sounds like an X/Y problem, why would you need to know what template you're in, when you're the one who wrote the templates, and they are all scoped to the parent file were they are included ?

Comment: since there are many templates that I used and I don't want to go through all of them manually, I want to see if there is any other way possible to do it automatically.

Comment: But why does your templates need to know the filename, I can't think of any reason the filename of the current template would be relevant to the template itself?

Comment: since I have separate pages like '/single/test1' that only shows one of the divs. while in the home directory I see all those divs in one page. and I would like to have links to all those separate pages in my homepage so they could be scraped.

Comment: I'm guessing the only way to do this, would be to either change EJS and add something in the `include` function, or write middleware that somehow hooks into that function ?

Answer (score 0):

send the filename (which you want to render) in include statement.

```
<%- include('test1', {filename: 'data'}) %>
```

inside test1 ejs

```
<div>
<h2>header info</h2>
<p>some text comes here</p>
<a href="/<% filename %>"><a>
</div>
```